# Invoke a specific JUnit test programmatically

Tags: java, junit

I would like to run a specific JUnit test method programmatically.  I know I can run the whole test using the following code snippet:

```
Class<?> test = Class.forName("MyTestClass");
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
Result result = junit.run(test);
```

However, I would like to run a specific method within this test class which contains multiple methods.

It would also be fantastic if I could control the setUp/tearDown behaviour.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an overloaded [JUnitCore#run](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html#run%28org.junit.runner.Request%29) method version that accepts `Request`. While `Request` has [Request#method](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/Request.html#method%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) factory method to:

> Create a Request that, when processed, will run a single test. This is
>   done by filtering out all other tests. This method is used to support
>   rerunning single tests.

If you need to control `#setUp` / `#tearDown` (i.e., methods marked with `@Before` and/or `@After` annotations) you can extend the class and override methods you need to alter.